# How can i get utf-8 char number from binary in c++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, binary

For example, I have: `11100011 10000010 10100010`. It is the binary of: `ア`;
its number in UTF-8 is:`12450`

How can I get this number from binary?

Comment: "its number in UTF-8 is " You mean, it's Unicode value ([called a code point](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)) is that.

Comment: This is surprisingly non-trivial.  If you're going to manipulating unicode in any way, get yourself a unicode library to do the work for you.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It's [not *that* bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Description). Though I agree that there's nothing to be gained by implementing it yourself when you have [stuff like this lying around](http://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/).

Comment: It is some kind of homework so I have to do it 'manually' ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The byte sequence you're showing is the UTF-8 encoded version of the character.

You need to *decode* the UTF-8 to get to the Unicode code point.

For this exact sequence of bytes, the following bits make up the code point:

```
11100011 10000010 10100010
    ****   ******   ******
```

So, concatenating the asterisked bits we get the number `0011000010100010`, which equals 0x30a2 or 12450 in decimal.

See the [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) for details on how to interpret the encoding.

In a nutshell: if bit 7 is set in the first byte, the number of adjacent bits (call it *m*) that are also set (2) gives the number of bytes that follow for this code point. The number of bits to extract from each byte is (8 - 1 - 1 - *m*) for the first byte, and 6 bits from each subsequent byte. So here we got (8 - 1 - 1 - 2) = 4 + 2 * 6 = 16 bits.

As pointed out in comments, there are plenty of libraries for this, so you might not need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

working from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), I came up with this:

```
unsigned utf8_to_codepoint(const char* ptr) {
    if( *ptr < 0x80) return *ptr;
    if( *ptr < 0xC0) throw unicode_error("invalid utf8 lead byte");
    unsigned result=0;
    int shift=0;
    if( *ptr < 0xE0) {result=*ptr&0x1F; shift=1;}
    if( *ptr < 0xF0) {result=*ptr&0x0F; shift=2;}
    if( *ptr < 0xF8) {result=*ptr&0x07; shift=3;}
    for(; shift>0; --shift) {
        ++ptr;
        if (*ptr<0x7F || *ptr>=0xC0) 
            throw unicode_error("invalid utf8 continuation byte");
        result <<= 6;
        result |= *ptr&0x6F;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that this is a very poor implementation (I highly doubt it even compiles), and parses a lot of invalid values that it probably shouldn't.  I put this up merely to show that it's a lot harder than you'd think, and that you should use a good unicode library.